# why run time error occured in GAS with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'd like to chanege my Python code into GAS.
I made this to find ranks matching searching keywords in 15

```
 function getRank() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=view&sm=tab_jum&query=%EC%96%B4%EB%A6%B0%EC%9D%B4%ED%99%8D%EC%82%BC').getContentText();
  var $ = Cheerio.load(html);
  var titleLists = $('.api_txt_lines')
  Logger.log(titleLists)
  for(var i=0; i<15; i++){
    Logger.log(titleLists[i])
    i++
  } 
 }
```

I found that Cheerio in GAS can parse HTML.
I could get the first text in 'titleLists' using .first().text() after $() context, but could not get the list of 'titleLists' saying that "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly".

How can I get all the lists of '.api_txt_lines'

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the text of those into an array?

```
var titleLists = $('.api_txt_lines').get().map(el => $(el).text())
```